# Calling action after SelectedIndex change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, panorama-control

I am newbie in MVVMLight. I want to call some method after panorama tab is changed. I would like to have information about selected panorama tab. A Problem is, HandlePanoramaViewSelected method is not called.

I cannot make it working. Don't know what is wrong

xaml:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="mainViewPanorama">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command ="{Binding PanoramaSelectedViewCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=mainViewPanorama}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:Panorama>
```

constructor:

```
PanoramaSelectedViewCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(x => HandlePanoramaViewSelected(x));
```

viewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> PanoramaSelectedViewCommand { get; set; }

private void HandlePanoramaViewSelected(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: That's not clear. What exactly your problem is?

Comment: Method HandlePanoramaViewSelected is not called

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different approaches. Please do only ONE of the following examples:

**Pass Event Args**

XAML:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="mainViewPanorama">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command ="{Binding PanoramaSelectedViewCommand}"
                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Property and Handler:

```
public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> PanoramaSelectedViewCommand { get; set; }

private void HandlePanoramaViewSelected(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // do something
}
```

Constructor:

```
PanoramaSelectedViewCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(HandlePanoramaViewSelected);
```

**Pass Command Parameter**

XAML:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="mainViewPanorama">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command ="{Binding PanoramaSelectedViewCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=mainViewPanorama}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Property and Handler:

```
public RelayCommand<object> PanoramaSelectedViewCommand { get; set; }

private void HandlePanoramaViewSelected(object selectedItem)
{
    // do something
}
```

Constructor:

```
PanoramaSelectedViewCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(HandlePanoramaViewSelected);
```